# How to get Oracle to return unique results in a one to many relationship tables with a left join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a three tables
Table 1

```
Id  Department
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

Table 2

```
Id  DepartId    Name
1   1           ABC
2   1           DEF
3   1           ASD
4   2           FGH
5   2           HJK
6   3           ZXC
```

Table 3

```
Id  Depart  Area
1   A       pp
2   B    
3   C       nn
4   D       oo
```

I need the result

```
Id  Depart  Name    Area
1   A       ABC     pp
2   B       FGH     Null
3   C       ZXC     nn
4   D       NULL    oo
```

I need one matching entry from table 2 and table 3 to corresponding entry in the table 1

Comment: @Nikil . . . It is rude to change a question after people have answered it.  Your new question invalidates the answers -- that people put effort into.  Invalid answers can attract downvotes.  The better course of action is to ask another question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I felt the inital question did not correctly explain my query

Comment: . . The best thing to do (in my opinion) is to ask another question.  The important thing to consider is whether changing the question will result in invalidating answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `left join` to also get t1 rows without any reference in the t2 table. `GROUP BY` to get only 1 row per Department.

```
select t1.id, t1.Department, min(t2.Name)
from t1
  left join t2 on t1.id = t2.DepartId
group by t1.id, t1.Department
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.name
        from t2
        where t1.id = t2.DepartId and rownum = 1
       ) as t2name
from t1;
```

This saves the overhead of an aggregation.  An index on `t2(DepartId, name)` is optimal for this query.

Answer (score 0):

by the way not the answer to your specific question but if instead of just one you want all the names you can use listagg

```
SELECT t1.id,
         department,
         LISTAGG (name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) names
    FROM t1, t2
   WHERE t1.id = t2.departId(+)
GROUP BY t1.id, department
ORDER BY 1

ID    Department         Names
1     A                  ABC,ASD,DEF
2     B                  FGH, HJK
3     C                  ZXC
4     D
```